# Webview doesn't fit fullscreen with action bar on

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar, fill-parent

I want to have webview displayed fullscreen with action bar on top of it and standard menu bar on bottom. It's displayed correctly without action bar. When I am turning it on, bottom part of webview is displayed *under* bottom menu bar and I want to fit it between both menu bars. 
Its probably easy fix but can't find answer on that. 
Thanks!

Code:

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layerType="software"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item android:id="@+id/opt" android:android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:enabled="true" android:title="Option 1" android:visible="true"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/opt2" android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" android:enabled="true" android:title="Option 2" android:visible="true"></item>

    </group>

</menu>
```

**activity:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    this.menu = menu;




    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Relative Layout in order to fit things in the right way.**

Show us more code in order to obtain for a better answer :D

**MOD**

Options menu is not made usually for fit into your layout , but overlapping it . I tell you to consider creating a fixed real menu which hides whenever you want with some action.

**Also think that menu can't have a fixed size and it may change with orientation , mobile phone , android version . Then if you could made what you need , you'll have more problems with your layout than making a custom one.**

Answer (score 2):

> android:windowActionBarOverlay Declares whether the action bar should
>   overlay the activity layout rather than offset the activity's layout
>   position This is false by default.
>
> When overlay mode is enabled, your activity layout has no awareness of
>   the action bar laying on top of it.

More about Actionbars can be read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: It should be false. I want actionbar to displace my view and set&fit them directly between action bar and bottom bar - is it possible?

Comment: @Piotr as far as I know, you're looking for the split action Bar, which is only available for devices running on Android 4.0. Otherwise A.Quiroga is right

Comment: Gosh, thats bummer. So is it possible to move action bar items back to bottom bar?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this I can't answer... I haven't read anything in the documentation about moving it to the bottom (I just looked again...). You can either try to find some info about this or go with A.Quiroga's method.